# Syntax select in SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with data like below :
TransM
TransD
The tables can see in the below

When I use syntax like below :

```
SELECT M.Kode_Project, M.Nama_Project, M.Kode_Panel,
       M.Nama_Panel,D.Kode_Stater,
       D.Nama_Stater1,
       D.Tipe, D.Komponen, D.Pole, D.Amps, D.Merek, D.Qty,
       D.IsTitipan
FROM TransM M
INNER JOIN TransD D
    ON M.Kode_Project = D.Kode_Project
       AND M.Kode_Panel = D.Kode_Panel
 WHERE (M.Kode_Project = '17-0002')
   AND (M.Kode_Panel = 'A')
```

[Tables And Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8bAV.jpg)

What's the wrong in my syntax? Pls Help Me

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your syntax (that would result in an error), your expectation is off. You are joining 2 identical records (identical with respect to the join conditions) with 4 other identical records. You get a Cartesian product (4*2=8). Looks like you can reduce it a bit by using `Kode_Stater` in the join as well, but that's still not unique. You should ask someone who knows your data and tables what the correct join conditions are.

Answer (score 0):

could be you need  the distinct result (this should remove duplicated rows)

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           M.Kode_Project, M.Nama_Project, M.Kode_Panel,
           M.Nama_Panel,D.Kode_Stater,
           D.Nama_Stater1,
           D.Tipe, D.Komponen, D.Pole, D.Amps, D.Merek, D.Qty,
           D.IsTitipan
    FROM TransM M
    INNER JOIN TransD D
        ON M.Kode_Project = D.Kode_Project
           AND M.Kode_Panel = D.Kode_Panel
     WHERE (M.Kode_Project = '17-0002')
       AND (M.Kode_Panel = 'A')
```

Comment: when u use select distinct the result will be wrong because the result will be only 2 records. The true result the must appear 4 records

Comment: Then  update  your question and add  the real expected  result  .. because is not clear  what do you need ..